# How to remove margin at bottom of print/PDF in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing

I have a simple html page (code below).  The width and height of the page and elements is 1587.4px and 2245.04px respectively.  These are set on the @page and elements.  I'm expecting a completely red page, no margins/borders).  However I'm getting a white margin/line at the bottom of the PDF (using Google Chrome's Save As PDF).   I suspect its an issue with scaling or box-model.  Not sure.

I've put in background colors to body and a parent element to see if that is bleeding through and it isn't.  The line is white so it is being added by Chrome for some reason.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
    <style>
      @page {
        size: 1587.4px 2245.04px;
        margin: 0;
      }

      body {
        padding: 0;
        background-color: green;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
      }

      .page {
        margin: 0;
            top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: relative;
        background-color: blue;
      }

      .element {
        margin: 0;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class='page' style="width: 1587.4px; height: 2245.04px;">
        <div class='element image' style='top: 0; left: 0; width: 1587.4px; height: 2245.04px;'>
            <div style="background-color: red;width: 1587.4px; height: 2245.04px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: It seems to only be an issue at these dimensions.  I tried 500 x 500 and 1936 x 1936 and no white line appeared.  Even doubling the dimensions used in the example above worked fine.

Comment: You could try pesticide chrome extensión to see if there is something that you are not seeing.

Comment: Tried it and wasn't able to see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: hey. Did you solve this? I have the same problem..